# I made a discord bot that assigns the role of a member but it is not working

Tags: discord.py

This is my code I am using repl it

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    member = message.author

    
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Member', message.guild.roles)
    if role in member.roles :
      await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + " please move this conversation to #unverified-chat")

    else:
      var = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Member")
      if member is not None :
        await member.add_roles(var)
        await message.channel.send('Hello ' + message.author.mention + '! You have been granted the role of a member')

keep_alive()
client.run(token)
```

I get error even when I have given the bot administrator permission :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 24, in on_message
    await member.add_roles(var)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 777, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

The error says that I haven't given the bot required permissions but I have given it all the permissions (Administrator Permission included). Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Who are you tring to assign the role to? If the role is on the same, or even an higher hierarchy level than your bot, this won't work. I.e. the bot can't assign the role to other administrators, or the guild owner

Comment: @@itzFlubby I am trying to assign the role to myself. I am not the server owner so I ask my friend to remove my admin/moderator status on the server before testing

Comment: With what permissions was the bot added to the server? You should have selected the required permissions in https://discord.com/developers/applications/<your-application-id>/oauth2

Comment: @@itzFlubby yes it was added with those permissions.